# show iframe in Outlook add-on

Tags: iframe, outlook, outlook-addin

Is it possible to develop an add-on to Outlook 2007 that will appear under the task box(or anywhere else). The add-on will be a simple iframe like the HTML tag.

For example I want to show sport results site in this iframe.

This this possible? How can you create a 'frame' for use by an Outlook add-on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps a "custom task pane" would be sufficient for your use:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942864(v=VS.90).aspx

You can then place a WebBrowser control in your task pane and put whatever HTML you want in there.